# Creating a new vector and basing its components on the previous iteration of another vector?

Tags: r

I am trying to test the profitability of a hypothesis I have for valuing stock options. Below is a simplidied version of what I am trying to do. When the evaluating variable (eee) goes below - 1, I want it to buy, then I want to 
hold until it goes back above -1 (as opposed to keep buying). So I am trying to create a logical vector (fff) for when eee goes below -1. ggg is then supposed to be a logical vector based on whether fff is TRUE and its previous component is FALSE.

```
 eee <-NULL

for(i in 1:500){
 eee[i] <- rnorm(n= 500) 
}

fff <- eee <= -1


ggg <- NULL

for(i in 1:500){
  if(fff[i - 1] == FALSE){
    ggg[i] <- fff[i]
  }else{
    ggg[i] <- FALSE
  }
}
```

It all works how its supposed to until the last for loop returns the following:

```
Error in if (fff[i - 1] == FALSE) { : argument is of length zero
```

Comment: In `R` index starts from 1.  So `i-1` is 0.  Did you meant `2:500`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you wanted to do this. The loop you had for `eee` just replaced it many time with random gaussian variables, so there's no need for it and since you want to look up `i-1` you have to start the loop one later, from 2.

```
eee <- rnorm(n= 500) 
fff <- eee <= -1
ggg <- vector(mode = "logical", length = 500)

for(i in 2:500){

  if(fff[i - 1] == FALSE){
    ggg[i] <- fff[i]
  }else{
    ggg[i] <- FALSE
  }
}
```